# Creating a chain of Vertx handler executions

Tags: java, future, vert.x, chain

From the start, sorry for bad English, I am working on it.

My goal is to create http methods in vert.x. Each method consists of steps, which can be blocked by other steps. For simplifying one step can be blocked by exactly one another.

I decided to create an AsyncMethodHandler which inside of `handle` method call, create exemplars of AsyncStepHandlers. Method handler also creates a map of steps futures, and try to create a compose handler for them to join.

here's the code `AsyncMethodHandler`:

```
public abstract class AsyncMethodHandler<T extends BaseChannelResponse> implements Handler<RoutingContext> {

    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_JSON = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    private final List<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>> steplist;
    private final HttpMethod methodType;
    private final String endpointName;
    private final HttpEndpointName endpoint;
    private String responseEndpoint;

    public AsyncMethodHandler(HttpEndpointName endpoint, String endpointName, HttpMethod methodType, List<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>> steplist) {
        this.steplist = steplist;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        this.endpointName = endpointName;
        this.methodType = methodType;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(RoutingContext event) {
        try {
            Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(steplist.size());
            List<AsyncStepHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<>(steplist.size());

            for (Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler> stepClass : this.steplist) {
                AsyncStepHandler stepHandler = stepClass.getConstructor(RoutingContext.class).newInstance(event);
                mapOfExecution.put(stepClass, stepHandler.getStepFuture());
                handlers.add(stepHandler);
            }
            for (AsyncStepHandler stepHandler : handlers) {
                stepHandler.before(mapOfExecution).setHandler(stepHandler.makeHandler(mapOfExecution));
            }

            CompositeFuture.join(new ArrayList<>(mapOfExecution.values())).setHandler(handleResult(event, mapOfExecution));

        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Handler<AsyncResult<CompositeFuture>> handleResult(RoutingContext event, Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution) {
        return result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                succeeded(event.response(), generateResponse(mapOfExecution));
            } else {
                ChannelAPIException error = ChannelAPIException.createFrom(result.cause());
                errored(event.response(), error.getCode(), error.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }

    protected abstract T generateResponse(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution);

    private void errored(HttpServerResponse response, int code, String message) {
        response.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)
                .setStatusCode(code)
                .end(message);
        CAPIMetricFactory.incBotResponseError(this.responseEndpoint, code);
    }

    private void succeeded(HttpServerResponse response, T result) {
        response.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)
                .setStatusCode(200)
                .end(Serializer.toPrettyJson(result));
        CAPIMetricFactory.incBotResponse(this.responseEndpoint);
    }

    public String getEndpointName() {
        return endpointName;
    }

    public HttpMethod getMethodType() {
        return methodType;
    }

    public HttpEndpointName getEndpoint() {
        return endpoint;
    }

    public void setResponseEndpoint(String responseEndpoint) {
        this.responseEndpoint = responseEndpoint;
    }
}
```

here's the code `AsyncStepHandlers`:

```
public abstract class AsyncStepHandler<T> {

    private final Future stepFuture;
    private final RoutingContext context;
    private final Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler> before;

    public AsyncStepHandler(RoutingContext context) {
        this(Future.future(), context, null);
    }

    public AsyncStepHandler(RoutingContext context, Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler> before) {
        this(Future.future(), context, before);
    }

    private AsyncStepHandler(Future stepFuture, RoutingContext context, Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler> before) {
        this.stepFuture = stepFuture;
        this.context = context;
        this.before = before;
    }

    public static <T> T getResultFromMap(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution, Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler> key) {
        return (T) mapOfExecution.get(key).result();
    }

    public final Future getStepFuture() {
        return stepFuture;
    }

    public RoutingContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public Buffer getContextBody() {
        return context.getBody();
    }

    public String getContextBodyAsString() {
        return context.getBodyAsString();
    }

    public Future before(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution) {
        if (before != null) {
            return mapOfExecution.get(before);
        } else {
            return Future.succeededFuture();
        }
    }

    public abstract Future<T> execute(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution);

    public Handler<AsyncResult> makeHandler(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution) {
        return result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                this.execute(mapOfExecution).setHandler(this.finish());
            } else {
                stepFuture.fail(result.cause());
            }
        };
    }

    private Handler<AsyncResult<T>> finish() {
        return result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                stepFuture.complete(result.result());
            } else {
                stepFuture.fail(result.cause());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So then, I try to create some actual methods and steps. For example:

1. create parameters object from the request body
2. from created earlier parameters get token and try to authorize
3. from an authorized object from the previous step consider validating the status of the request.

So here's the code:

```
public class SimpleTestMethod extends AsyncMethodHandler<TestData> {

public SimpleTestMethod(String endpoint) {
    super(
            CHANNEL_API_SEND_TEXT,
            endpoint,
            POST,
            new ArrayList<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>>(){{
                add(ParametersStep.class);
            }{
                add(AuthorizationStep.class);
            }{
                add(ValidateStep.class);
            }}
    );
}

@Override
protected TestData generateResponse(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution) {
    System.out.println("End");
    SendMessageParameters response = (SendMessageParameters) mapOfExecution.get(ParametersStep.class).result();
    ValidationResult validationResult = (ValidationResult) mapOfExecution.get(ValidateStep.class).result();
    return new TestData(response.toString(),0l);
}
```

}

First if for example steps will be like this:

```
public class ParametersStep extends AsyncStepHandler<SendMessageParameters> {

public ParametersStep(RoutingContext context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public Future<SendMessageParameters> execute(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution) {
    System.out.println("ParametersStep");
    SendMessageParameters parameters = parseJson(this.getContextBodyAsString(), SendMessageParameters.class);
    return Future.succeededFuture(parameters);
}
```

}

Execution will be expectable. But if I will add some additional awaiting for some step, then the next after that step will never start.

For example:

```
public class AuthorizationStep extends AsyncStepHandler<AuthResponse> {

public AuthorizationStep(RoutingContext context) {
    super(context, ParametersStep.class);
}

@Override
public Future<AuthResponse> execute(Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution) {
    System.out.println("AuthorizationStep");
    final Future<AuthResponse> authorization = Future.future();
    SendMessageParameters parameters = getResultFromMap(mapOfExecution, ParametersStep.class);
    AuthResponse response = new AuthResponse(new ChannelTokenData(0l,parameters.getToken(),true,0l,0l,null));

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            authorization.complete(response);
        }
    });
    t.start();

    return authorization;
}
```

}

Then no steps, that awaits of authorization step ending will be called. I reading the official doc, and tried to find some information about this case, but did not succeed. I tried different technics `setHandler`, `compose` but get's the same result.

Can anybody help me with understanding why next step won't start and solving this issue because the next part is to use CompositeFuture =)

P.S.:
What is the most interesting, if for example AuthorizationStep  is second in 3 steps method - execution will stop on second step. But if I do this:

```
@Override
    public void handle(RoutingContext event) {
        try {
            Map<Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler>, Future> mapOfExecution = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(steplist.size());
            List<AsyncStepHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<>(steplist.size());
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(steplist.size());

            for (Class<? extends AsyncStepHandler> stepClass : this.steplist) {
                AsyncStepHandler stepHandler = stepClass.getConstructor(RoutingContext.class).newInstance(event);
                mapOfExecution.put(stepClass, stepHandler.getStepFuture());
                handlers.add(stepHandler);
                stepHandler.setLatch(latch);
            }
            for (AsyncStepHandler stepHandler : handlers) {
                stepHandler.before(mapOfExecution).setHandler(stepHandler.makeHandler(mapOfExecution));
            }

            latch.await();
            CompositeFuture.join(new ArrayList<>(mapOfExecution.values())).setHandler(handleResult(event, mapOfExecution));

        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this in AsyncStepHandler:

```
private Handler<AsyncResult<T>> finish() {
        return result -> {
            System.out.println("finish");
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                latch.countDown();
                stepFuture.complete(result.result());
            } else {
                stepFuture.fail(result.cause());
            }
        };
    }
```

Everything starts to work. If I add countdown latch, and add await before Composite future join, all will be fine.